# how to check from where the connections are coming to AWS RDS Postgres t2 micro instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My AWS t2 micro instance was working fine, but now i'm facing a problem  that suddenly the number of connections are going more than 85 and the instance is not responding. normally it was less than 10. How to troubleshoot this issue? It would be great to get some help.

Comment: Not an answer, but the first thing to do is see whether you can find a reason for so many new connections.

Comment: Check [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure out that? I can only see monitoring graphs and checked for documentation, but nothing helped.

Comment: Can't you run a `select * from pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: Easiest solution is to use a connection pooler somewhere.. the pooler can limit connections, and share them in a way to keep the number down low and to stop fluctuating as to reduce resource consumption.